# Database insert error: "string or binary data would be truncated"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

When I log in, I am storing my username in the session. My requirement is that I want to store my username in my database. Here I am storing it in `username1`. When the username is entered, I can print it using `response.write()` and it is printing perfectly. However, when I am storing it in the database it is producing this error:

```
**sqlException was unhandled by user code
and exception at       cmd.ExecuteScalar();
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.**
```

Following is my ado.net code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = 
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;database=testdb1;Integrated Security=SSPI")) {

    con.Open();
    //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from fileinfo where ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["one"]), con);                            

    string uname = (string) Session["fname"].ToString() + " " + Session["lname"].ToString(); //Session["fname"].ToString()+" "+Session["lname"].ToString();

    // Response.Write(uname);
    // uname = "sri hari";
    uname = uname + " ";
    string uname1 = uname;
    uname = uname.Trim();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into qry_details values('" + txt_query_name.Text + "','pending for approval','" + txt_query_description.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','" + qry + "','" + uname1 + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column into which you are trying to insert the username? The value stored in `uname` is longer than the length of this column.

Comment: @srihari: you need to check your table schemas, datatypes and query like `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (@value1,@value2,@value3,...);` you might be facing column mismatch

Comment: Am I the only person trying to analyse injection risk?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

check the length of qry_details table and see if its smaller than the string you send to the db?

basically the exception says you are trying to something bigger than the column length.

Comment: but if asigning string value directly it is inserting like uname="srihari" if iam inserting with session it is giving exception

Comment: i gave uname value 50 length

Comment: @srihari, then what is the value of `uname.Length`?

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend you using a parametrized query. Your code is now vulnerable to SQL injection. Also you should use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method on the SQL command instead of `ExecuteScalar` when inserting values to the database:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=.;database=testdb1;Integrated Security=SSPI";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO qry_details VALUES (@query_name, 'pending for approval', @query_description, @date, @qry, @username)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query_name", txt_query_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query_description", txt_query_description.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qry", qry);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", uname1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: string uname 1= (string)Session["fname"].ToString() + " " + Session["lname"].ToString();

Comment: But what about the "string or binary data would be truncated" error?

Comment: then also same exception is coming.exception is     String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: it is giving at     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1):

This error mostly happen when the inserting value is larger than the field width defined in table on SQL Server.

Check if you are inserting date and time using DateTime.Now c# fuction, your Table must be of type DateTime. not Date or Time only.