# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@cid' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I have the following set of codes for update.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Patching_Dates set Patch_Date='@date',Day_Date='@day' where Month='@month' and Customer_Id='@cid' and Year='@year'", cnn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
```

cid is integer type.

While running this I get the error as "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@cid' to data type int" Could you please help in this.

```
Table Structure:

Customer_Id int
E_ID varchar(1)
Year varchar(4)
Month varchar(10)
Day_Date varchar(2)
S_ID int primary key
Patch_Date varchar(10)

C# data types
 cid=int
 all other data types are in strings which ever is in parameters.

Query which worked in sql server management studio
update Patching_Dates set Patch_Date='1/19/2014',Day_Date='19' where Month='January' and Customer_Id='11' and Year='2014';
```

Comment: maybe you dont need single quotes here Customer_Id='@cid'  ??? Should be just Customer_Id=@cid

Comment: Remove quotes around @cid. it should be `Customer_Id=@cid`

Comment: @Darka I get this on removing quotes "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated"

Comment: @Rahul I get this on removing quotes "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated"

Comment: it simply means that you are trying to insert a value more than the size of that column. From your table schema what is size of `Customer_Id` and what value does variable `cid` has?

Comment: @Rahul Query very well works in Sql Server Management Studio. With replacing that parameters with data

Comment: In that case problem is with variable `cid`. How you are getting `cid` and what type it is?

Comment: @Rahul cid value is got by this way "int cid = Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());"

Comment: Maybe this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/17312621/1692632

Comment: try changing your command to the following where data tpe is specified. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cid;`

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Not working.

Comment: @Rahul this works for insert query only for update its not working

Comment: what error do you get, did you convert all parameters to this structure?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @ChetanGoenka can you include your table structure? Also include datatype of your C# variables.

Comment: Are you sure that this error is for cid?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Added in the question

Comment: all suggestions in internet say that one of the parameters is to long ...

Comment: @Darka so what you suggest?

Comment: you give same values and from asp ? what about E_ID?

Comment: You should run it in debug mode, and look at the values of parameters before cmd is executed. You might think that one thing is being passed in but something else is going in. Copy entire command string.

Comment: I would just put same update (which you put here) into code and execute it. If it will work then something bad is coming from parameters.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky everything is being passed crctly.

Comment: have you tried to execute statement from application directly against DB?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky without parameters it is working from application. its getting updated.

Comment: @Darka It works from code. When debug all parameters are having crct values

Comment: have you tried putting all parameters except Cid? Put some int value inside update

Comment: Thanks all. I found the solution. I removed quotes from everything n executed. It worked.

Comment: oh yea can be that ... forgot. System adds it. ... :D