# please fix "String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to find the old co-ordinate and replace it with a new co-ordinate in my Database using C# WPF. I got this error

> String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated

and I couldn't find what's the problem. This is my method that I used:

```
 public void updateEvent(string oldCord,string newCord, DateTime dropDate)
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Event SET Date = @newDate ,Cordinate=@newCord  WHERE  Cordinate = @oldCord";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newDate", dropDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newCord", newCord);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldCord", oldCord);             
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This exception is thrown because you're trying to write more data into a field of a table than would fit into it. Like a `string` with 100 characters into a `varchar(50)` field. So the question is, how exactly is the field `Cordinate` (should probably be named `Coordinate`) defined and how long exactly is the `newCord` you try to write into it?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: How about this post 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312558/database-insert-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated'?

Comment: We need to see the table declaration in order to know the length of the column values.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the cause for this issue is that the length of the parameter you send to the stored procedure is bigger than the size of the field in the actual table in the database.